# Probability of matching at least one number in lotto

Tags: probability

If you buy one lotto ticket, what is the theoretical probability of matching at least one of your numbers? In this lotto you pick 6 numbers between 1 and 49. How do I go about finding this?

Comment: Do you have to match all 6? IF the lotto picks six and you have to match, it's $1/{49\choose 6}$.  Or does the lotto pick more than six?

Comment: The lotto picks six but you don't have to match all 6. I'm looking for the probability that out of those six winning numbers, your lotto ticket matches "at least" 1 number. Thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chance to match at least one number  is the complement of matching none of the numbers.

There are $\binom {49-6}{6}$ possibilities to match none out of a total of $\binom {49}{6}$ possibilities.

Therefore the probability to match at least one is:
$$1 - \frac{\binom {49-6}{6}}{\binom {49}{6}}$$

Comment: @I like Serena, sorry,I did not see your answer before starting my typing.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the 43 non-winning numbers. You can match none of the winning numbers by choosing any 6 from these 43. Then the probability of matching at least one is 1-probability of matching none, i.e., $$1-\frac{{43\choose6}}{{49\choose6}} $$

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the other two answers, \[1 - \frac{\binom {43}{6}}{\binom {49}{6}}=\frac{6096454}{13983816}=\frac{563383}{998844}=0.564\dots\]

so the odds are a little better than half.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you don't need 43 out of 49, then you don't need 42 out of 48, and so on:

$1 - \frac{43}{49} * \frac{42}{48} * \frac{41}{47} * \frac{40}{46} * \frac{39}{45} * \frac{38}{44}$