# With $X$ possible and $Y$ of those winning, what is the probability that I will pick $Z$ winning if I choose N?

Tags: probability

I wasn't quite sure how to word this, but I basically am trying to do something similar to this: [Probability of matching at least one number in lotto](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/723845/probability-of-matching-at-least-one-number-in-lotto)

I scoured the internet and found many resources on "odds of picking $1-6$ lotto numbers" but they all are based around the idea that you pick the same amount of numbers as there are correct numbers.

The only difference is that I don't want to be forced to pick $6$ numbers, I want to be able to pick a variable amount between $1$ and the total count of numbers that exist.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: A more concrete example --

I have $32$ tiles flipped upside down. $3$ of the tiles are winning tiles. Now I get to select $5$ of those tiles, and then flip them all over at the same time. I want to be able to figure out the probability of me picking $0, 1, 2$, or $3$ of the winning tiles.

Comment: Try counting directly: you can count the number of ways to choose $N$ out of $X$ numbers, and then count the number of "winning hands." I'm not sure by how the question is phrased; the case for "exactly $Z$" winning numbers is generally easier than "at least $Z$"

Comment: This question is exactly like the question of "*what is the probability of getting exactly $k$ spades when drawing a hand of five cards from a standard deck of 52 cards*".  You might try searching for longer video explanations on that problem, but the short answer for your concrete example is, to pick exactly $k$ of the winning tiles you pick which $k$ they are and then you pick which $5-k$ other non-winning tiles they are giving a probability of $\dfrac{\binom{3}{k}\binom{29}{5-k}}{\binom{32}{5}}$

Comment: Thank you for the help, this is useful!

Comment: Also the keywords "hypergeometric distribution" may help your research.

Comment: @GrahamKemp wow that's perfect, that's exactly what it is. Thank you for that tidbit.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

- How many ways are there of choosing $Z$ winning numbers from $Y$?
- How many ways are there of choosing $N-Z$ losing numbers from $X-Y$?
- How many ways are there of choosing $N$ numbers from $X$?